# Featherlight.js and the WP Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, dom, featherlight.js

I have a bunch of images on my page that are linked to videos that open in a modal window, using [Featerlight.js](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#installation).

I'm using a loop to template my content in Wordpress, but it seems that all featherlight modals get pushed to the end of the document (after the footer).

So even though my code is written like this:

```
<?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>

    <?php // Start Loop // ?>
    <div class="col-xs-4">

        <?php // Start Modal Link // ?>
        <a class="thumb-link" data-featherlight="#video-modal">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" width="100%" height="auto" />
        </a>
        <?php // End Modal Link // ?>

        <?php // Start Modal Window // ?>
        <div id="video-modal" class="lightbox">
            <video controls style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
                <source src="<?php echo $video_link; ?>" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <?php // End Modal Window // ?>

    </div>
    <?php // End Loop // ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It appears like this when it's rendered:

```
<?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>

    <?php // Start Loop // ?>
    <div class="col-xs-4">

        <?php // Start Modal Link // ?>
        <a class="thumb-link" data-featherlight="#video-modal">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" width="100%" height="auto" />
        </a>
        <?php // End Modal Link // ?>

    </div>
    <?php // End Loop // ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

...

<?php // Start Modal Window // ?>
    <div id="video-modal" class="lightbox">
        <video controls style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
            <source src="<?php echo $video_link; ?>" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
<?php // End Modal Window // ?>
```

Obviously this isn't ideal as it's only pulling the first video in the loop, and each image links to the same video, since the video isn't contained in the loop. Has anyone else run into this issue, or does anyone have any advice on how to work around it?

Comment: Old question, I know. But the reason for this, is that you're effectively echoing the results, not returning it. I don't know where this code is, but that's the best reason I can come up with. Push the html output into a variable and return that at the end, instead.